# Python - Using string array, pass them as input for dataframe name for a function

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python, not sure if it is a stupid way of doing this (coz I might have thousands of stocks code).  I am trying to pass a list of stock code which there is a list of dataframe I created separately. I'd like to pass different dataframe, based on the arrary, into the function. Any suggestion on the best way to carry out this?

```
    def ind (in_df):
    in_df['CHG']= in_df['Open'] / in_df['Close']
    return ;

STK = ['GOOG','TSLA','AAPL']

for index in range(len(STK)):
    print (STK[index])
    ind(pd.DataFrame[STK[index]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the loop like below. That way you don't have to invoke len or individual list element separately.

```
STK = ['GOOG','TSLA','AAPL']

for stockCode in STK:
    print (stockCode)
    ind(pd.DataFrame[stockCode])
```

Comment: To extend this answer, it will serve you well to spend some time Reading The Friendly Python docs about iterators and generators and all the ways they can be created and consumed. And once you *think* you have a handle on them, go blow your mind by reading David Beazley's [Generator Tricks for System Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) and also the Related Tutorials. It was written in 2008 and I still go re-read it at least every other year.

Comment: Thank you very much